# Sort data with tidyverse based on criteria

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataframe consisting of two columns: ID and date_time. ID indicates who is being recorded and date_time indicates when. See a piece of the dataframe below.

From this dataframe I would like to calculate a new dataframe that has three columns: "Measurement", "ID" and "Date".

1. “Measurement”. This column should tell what number measurement this was of a given ID. A measurement starts at 23:00:00 and then runs until 22:59:59 the next day. A measurement however starts at random times and the duration of the first measurement is thus not 24 hours. Neither is the last measurement 24 hours.
2. “ID”. Indicate the ID of a given measurement
3. “Date”. This column should show the date of the last recording in a given measurement in this format: yyyy.mm.dd.

There should be a row for every unique measurement

```
structure(list(date_time = c("2020.03.02 22:00:17", "2020.03.02 22:05:17", 
"2020.03.02 22:10:17", "2020.03.02 22:35:17", "2020.03.02 22:40:17", 
"2020.03.02 22:45:17", "2020.03.02 22:50:17", "2020.03.02 22:55:17", 
"2020.03.02 23:00:17", "2020.03.02 23:05:17", "2020.03.02 23:10:17", 
"2020.03.02 23:15:17", "2020.03.02 23:20:17", "2020.03.02 23:25:17", 
"2020.03.02 23:30:17", "2020.03.02 23:35:17", "2020.03.02 23:40:17", 
"2020.03.02 23:45:17", "2020.03.02 23:50:17", "2020.03.02 23:55:17", 
"2020.03.03 00:00:17", "2020.03.03 00:55:17", "2020.03.03 01:00:17", 
"2020.03.03 01:05:17", "2020.03.03 01:10:17", "2020.03.03 01:15:17", 
"2020.03.03 01:20:17", "2020.03.03 01:25:17", "2020.05.09 08:39:32", 
"2020.05.09 08:39:32", "2020.05.09 08:39:32", "2020.05.09 08:39:32", 
"2020.05.09 08:39:32", "2020.05.09 08:39:32", "2020.05.09 08:39:32", 
"2020.05.09 08:39:32", "2020.05.09 08:39:32", "2020.05.09 08:39:32", 
"2020.05.09 08:39:32", "2020.05.09 08:39:32", "2020.05.09 08:39:32", 
"2020.05.09 08:39:32", "2020.05.09 08:39:32", "2020.05.09 08:39:32", 
"2020.05.09 08:39:32", "2020.05.09 08:39:32"), id = c(12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L)), row.names = c(NA, 46L), class = "data.frame")
#Expected output:
output <- read.table(header=TRUE, text ="
                     ID Date        Measurement
                     12 2020.03.02  1
                     12 2020.03.03  2
                     13 2020.05.09  1
")
```

I'm new to R and try to work with tidyverse.
All help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: can you share expected output? Also, by column ID, do you mean "case" column?

Comment: Thanks for commenting! I can see my question was unclear in several regards. I have tried to improve it. Let me know if still is unclear in any way.

Comment: in your question you say that your expected output has 3 columns, but in the expected output you show there are only two columns. Can you make it consistent? Also, at the moment it is not clear to me what a measurement is and what number you would expect to see.

Comment: Yes, I can see my question still was not clear. I have edited the text to make it more clear. Thanks for clearing this up.

Comment: Your question is still not clear on how to obtain measurement.  For the sample data you posted above is the expected output as you display at the bottom?  Then you are not meeting your criteria #3 as it is not "date of the last recording" for ID 13.

Comment: Yes YBS, you are right. Thanks for you comment. I have again edited the question so that it hopefully makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming df1 is your dataframe, another way to do is...

```
df1$dateTime = as_datetime(df1$date_time, format = "%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S")
df1$mydate = as.Date(df1$date_time, format = "%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S")

df1$tm <- as.numeric(df1$dateTime)
df1$dts <- 86400*as.numeric(df1$mydate)

df2 <- df1 %>% group_by(id,mydate) %>% 
         transform(date = case_when(((dts-3600)<tm & tm<(dts+82800) )~paste0(mydate),((dts+82800)<=tm)~paste0(mydate+1) )) %>% 
         select(id,date) %>%   unique() %>% 
         group_by(id) %>% mutate(measurement = row_number())
df2

>df2
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   id [2]
     id date       measurement
  <int> <chr>            <int>
1    12 2020-03-02           1
2    12 2020-03-03           2
3    13 2020-05-09           1
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's a better way of doing this but.....

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  structure(list(date_time = c("2020.03.02 22:00:17", "2020.03.02 22:05:17", 
                               "2020.03.02 22:10:17", "2020.03.02 22:35:17", "2020.03.02 22:40:17", 
                               "2020.03.02 22:45:17", "2020.03.02 22:50:17", "2020.03.02 22:55:17", 
                               "2020.03.02 23:00:17", "2020.03.02 23:05:17", "2020.03.02 23:10:17", 
                               "2020.03.02 23:15:17", "2020.03.02 23:20:17", "2020.03.02 23:25:17", 
                               "2020.03.02 23:30:17", "2020.03.02 23:35:17", "2020.03.02 23:40:17", 
                               "2020.03.02 23:45:17", "2020.03.02 23:50:17", "2020.03.02 23:55:17", 
                               "2020.03.03 00:00:17", "2020.03.03 00:55:17", "2020.03.03 01:00:17", 
                               "2020.03.03 01:05:17", "2020.03.03 01:10:17", "2020.03.03 01:15:17", 
                               "2020.03.03 01:20:17", "2020.03.03 01:25:17", "2020.05.09 08:39:32", 
                               "2020.05.09 08:39:32", "2020.05.09 08:39:32", "2020.05.09 08:39:32", 
                               "2020.05.09 08:39:32", "2020.05.09 08:39:32", "2020.05.09 08:39:32", 
                               "2020.05.09 08:39:32", "2020.05.09 08:39:32", "2020.05.09 08:39:32", 
                               "2020.05.09 08:39:32", "2020.05.09 08:39:32", "2020.05.09 08:39:32", 
                               "2020.05.09 08:39:32", "2020.05.09 08:39:32", "2020.05.09 08:39:32", 
                               "2020.05.09 08:39:32", "2020.05.09 08:39:32"), id = c(12L, 12L, 
                                                                                     12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
                                                                                     12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
                                                                                     13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
                                                                                     13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L)), row.names = c(NA, 46L), class = "data.frame")
)

df %>%
  mutate(
    date_time = anytime::anydate(date_time)
  ) %>%
  group_by(id) %>% summarise(date = unique(date_time)) %>%
  mutate(
    Measurement = 1,
    Measurement = cumsum(Measurement)
  )

# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   id [2]
     id date       Measurement
  <int> <date>           <dbl>
1    12 2020-03-02           1
2    12 2020-03-03           2
3    13 2020-05-09           1
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution also seem to work perfectly fine!

Comment: @Magnus, If `ID` 14 had the measurements `"2020.03.02 23:45:17", "2020.03.02 23:50:17", "2020.03.02 23:55:17",  "2020.03.03 00:00:17", "2020.03.03 00:55:17", "2020.03.03 01:00:17"`, it should be counted once per your criteria #1.  However, this solutions counts it as two (1, 2) measurements similar to the count for `ID` 12.

Comment: Yes, you are right! Your solution however works as it should.